NETWORKDAYS to calculate the number of business days when excluding company holidays
I am trying to calculate the number of business days between dates in two fields, excluding company holidays, which I have entered on a separate worksheet in a named range.
My code works if I don't try to exclude the holidays, but as soon as I add the range parameter, no value is returned.
This works:
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NETWORKDAYS([@[AdjAPSRecvdDt]],[@[APS_ACK_DT]])"

However, this does not:
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=NETWORKDAYS([@[AdjAPSRecvdDt]],[@[APS_ACK_DT]],Holidays!HRange)"

The code runs, but the fields in the spreadsheet have "#VALUE!"
I used the formula evaluator, and everything evaluates until it tries to calculate the final value.
The Evaluate Formula box before receiving the "#VALUE!" error:
NETWORKDAYS($K$2,$N$2,"Holidays!$A$2:$A$28")


Do the cells listing the holidays contain actual dates or text that look like a date?

They are formatted as dates. Thank you.

You can't use Holidays!HRange within a string - you have to supply the address.
Dim rgCompanyHolidays As Range
Set rgCompanyHolidays = Worksheets("Holidays").Names("HRange").RefersToRange

Dim strAdressCompanyHolidays As String
strAdressCompanyHolidays = rgCompanyHolidays.Address(External:=True)

ActiveCell.Formula = "=NETWORKDAYS(B9,C9," & strAdressCompanyHolidays & ")"



Set rgCompanyHolidays = Worksheets("Holidays").Names("HRange").RefersToRange   I get "Application-defined or object-defined error" on this line.

Is HRange a workbook name? Then you have to use Set rgCompanyHolidays = ThisWorkbook.Names("HRange").RefersToRange

HRange is a named range

@bethw12000 Welcome to SO :-) and allow me an hint as new participant:  it's good use and also helpful for other readers to mark a working solution (or the best one of several answers) as accepted if you found it helpful (acceptance is indicated by a colored checkmark next to the answer). C.f. "Someone answers"
How does accepting an answer work

So in the end, I used Ike's response and had to modify it a little to get it to work:
Dim rgCompanyHolidays As Range
Dim strCompanyHolidaysAddress As String

Set rgCompanyHolidays = Worksheets("Holidays").Range("A2:A28")
strCompanyHolidaysAddress = rgCompanyHolidays.Address(External:=True)
ActiveCell.Formula = "=NETWORKDAYS([@[AdjAPSRecvdDt]],[@[APS_ACK_DT]]," & _ 
   strCompanyHolidaysAddress & ")-1"

